# Why can I not catch my non-terminating error?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to show someone an example on how to catch non terminating errors in PowerShell.

I created this function:

```
# This will write a non-terminating error
function NonTerminatingErrorExample {
    Param($i = 5)
    if ($i -gt 4) {
        Write-Error "I expected a value less or equal to 4!" 
    }
    Write-Host "However, I can still continue the execution"
}
```

However, I can't catch it with `-ErrorAction Stop`

```
Try {
    NonTerminatingErrorExample -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Host "Now you see this message."
}
```

I never get the catch block returned. Why?

```
NonTerminatingErrorExample : I expected a value less or equal to 4!
In Zeile:32 Zeichen:5
+     NonTerminatingErrorExample -ErrorAction Stop
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,NonTerminatingErrorExample

However, I can still continue the execution
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function isn't a cmdlet and therefore doesn't support `-ErrorAction`. Add `[CmdletBinding()]` to the body to make it one and the parameter will be supported. You can see the difference if you `Get-Help` both versions: as a function, there is no `[<CommonParameters>]`.